# How do I add a column to the results that would show sequential numbers

Tags: oracle, sequential

How do I modify this SQL (or create a different SQL) such that it adds a column to the results - that would show sequential numbers that start with 1 and increases by 1

That is 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.

Note: I don't need to add an auto-increment column. I just need the incrementing column in the results if possible

```
select year, quarter, uploaddate, sum(wagecount) as wagecount from wage_reporting
group by year, quarter, uploaddate
order by year, quarter, uploaddate
```

Expected results would be something like this

| Year | Quarter | UploadDate | WageCount | SequentialNumbers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | 01-JAN-21 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021 | 1 | 02-JAN-21 | 2 | 2 |
| 2021 | 1 | 03-JAN-21 | 1 | 3 |
| 2021 | 1 | 04-JAN-21 | 5 | 4 |

Comment: Do you want to add a column in your data base that auto increments?

Comment: No. I know about autoincrement and that's not what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using subquery and rownum pseudo column will help

```
select your_query.*, rownum
  from (select year, quarter, uploaddate, sum(wagecount) as wagecount 
          from wage_reporting
         group by year, quarter, uploaddate
         order by year, quarter, uploaddate) your_query
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select year, quarter, uploaddate, sum(wagecount) as wagecount, SUM(1) OVER (ORDER BY year, quarter, uploaddate) as SequentialNumbers from wage_reporting
group by year, quarter, uploaddate
order by year, quarter, uploaddate
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
SELECT year, quarter, uploaddate, SUM(wagecount) AS wagecount,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY uploaddate) sequential_numbers
FROM wage_reporting
GROUP BY year, quarter, uploaddate
ORDER BY year, quarter, uploaddate;
```

Comment: better have the order by in the function be  'year, quarter,uploaddate', as this will eliminate a sort

Comment: In running your script, some numbers were skipped in the sequence